# Getting an error with excel ole "Add method of Workbooks class failed"

Tags: delphi, excel, ole

I am trying to open and refresh an excel 2003 spreadsheet via ole.  However I am getting the error "Add method of Workbooks class failed" with no further information.

The code works in unit tests, and works on 3 servers but fails with the error on our web server.  It is being run from a service app running under the Local System Account.

The same version of excel is installed on all servers (2003 sp3).  The file(s) in question all exist and are at the expected location.

There are no macros in the spreadsheets, but there are database queries.  The spreadsheets can all be opened.

The calling code is

```
if VarIsEmpty(XLApp) then
begin
  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    XLApp.DisplayAlerts:=  wdAlertsNone;
  except
...
  end;
  XLApp.AutomationSecurity:= msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable;
end;

fullFileName:= ExpandReportFileName( partialFilename);
if not FileExists(fullFileName) then
  raise Exception.Create('File not found: ' + fullFileName);

XLAPP.Workbooks.Add(fullFileName);  << fail here
```

Any ideas on what else I can try?

Answer (score 4):

I had been getting the same error for

```
xls.WorkBooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet);
```

I changed that line to

```
xls.Application.Workbooks.Add;
```

Now it is working. You might try to get a Workbook first then try to call its methods.

Comment: thank you; that was the exact same problem i was having as well.  fixed.

Comment: It was working for years. We develop solutions to fix something that was already working. *Sigh*

Answer (score 2):

Automating Office applications in a service is [not supported](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

While it is possible, it's very difficult, and you'll run into many problems, such as this one.  It'll also be very slow.

You should look for a Delphi component that manipulates Excel files.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to [use OLE DB instead](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel).

Answer (score 1):

`Workbooks.Open` might be the method you're looking for

`Add` creates a new empty workbook. If you supply a filename, that file is used as a template for the new file - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221688%28office.11%29.aspx)

`Open` just opens the file as you would expect - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195811%28office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Just tried that, it changes the error to "Open method of Workbooks class failed" :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error when I happened to have the Excel spreadsheet file selected in a Windows Explorer window, not open, just selected.  When I deselect the file, I do not get the error.

Comment: That's outrageous. I am dead inside